# Issue making list

Tags: r

below is the list generated by the function `locate_areas` from library tabulizer. I want to reproduce this list but this time with code.

[image]

I can't get exactly the same list, anyone can help? (i.e. issue seem to be the double [1 x 4] instead of double [4].

```
L <- c("top","left","bottom","right")
R <- c(26.09,96.6,36.73,326.6)

R <- t(R)
L <- t(L)
names(R) <- L
x <- list(R)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare again R in the combine (`c()`)

```
R <- t(R)
L <- t(L)
names(R) <- L
x <- list(c(R))

View(x)
```